# GridView on ScrollView (application doing too much work on its main thread)

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a gridview (expandableHeightGridView) that lays within a scrollView.

When the gridview contains 4 pictures it works fine. However, if I add 2 more, it becomes unresponsive or very laggy. A log message appears saying that I am doing too much work on the main thread. I have tried to create asyncTask to handle some of the work but nothing seems to work.

This is my Main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends GeneralActivity {
    private ExpandableHeightGridView gv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        gv = (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.MainActivity_gv);
        gv.setExpanded(true);       

        GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this);
        gv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void onClickDestaques1(View v) {
        Log.v("LOG", "numero 1");
    }

    public void onClickDestaques2(View v){
        Log.v("LOG", "numero 2");
    }

    public void onClickDestaques3(View v){
        Log.v("LOG", "numero 3");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        Intent intent;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.pontos:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HistoricoDePontosActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.info:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlterarInfoActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.senha:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlterarSenhaActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.config:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ConfiguracoesActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.ajuda:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AjudaActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The Main xml class:

```html
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_padding" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="CPF: 947665665-45"
            android:textColor="#846248"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Saldo: 150 pts"
            android:textColor="#153515"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bem-vindo, GUSTAVO"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Aqui esta escrito algo interessante mas totalmente irrelevante." />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.br.ExpandableHeightGridView
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_gv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#0266c8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Destaques"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_padding"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:onClick="onClickDestaques1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/icone1land" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_padding"
        android:onClick="onClickDestaques2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/icone1land" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_padding"
        android:onClick="onClickDestaques3"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/icone1land" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_padding"
        android:textSize="200sp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is the GridAdapter class:

```
class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public GridAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;

        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.icone1land, JunteActivity.class));
        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.icone2land, TroqueActivity.class));
        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.icone3land, DeliveryActivity.class));
        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.icone4land, EventosActivity.class));
        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.icone5land, ReservasActivity.class));
        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.icone6land, ContatosActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return items.get(i).drawableId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_inflater_gridview, viewGroup, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag(); 
        }

        final Item item = (Item) getItem(i);

        holder.img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        holder.img.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
        holder.img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, item.activityClass);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {  
        ImageView img; 
    }
}
```

The expandableGrid class:

```
public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView {

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded()) {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

and the squareImageView class:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {
    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
    }
}
```

Please help me. I am stuck on this problem for a while. Couldnt solve my problem with existing questions on the matter, thus I need a more customisable answer. Thanks you!

Comment: probably because your images are to big

Comment: Thanks, I will have a check on it!

Comment: I guess you solved the problem easily mate, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images were too big and for that reason I was getting these error messages. I resized my images and suddenly everything started to work just fine! Thanks   @tyczj for your comment